# gcc report unreferenced symbol for version based library

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++

One of my shared library my.so use version based symbol as symbol@@test_1.2.3 from library test.so. When I link my.so shared library with my executable, it says 'unreferenced symbol symbol@@test_1.2.3'. This happens when link line is as follows -

```
g++ -o myexecutable myexecutable.o -L/path-to-my.so -lmy -L/path-to-test.so -ltest
```

If I change the link link to -

```
g++ -o myexecutable myexecutable.o -L/path-to-my.so -lmy /path-to-test.so/libtest.so
```

it works.

Why is `libtest.so` not picked up when specified with `-L` but does when given as complete path?

Comment: Did you try swapping the order of `-ltest` and `-lmy` in the first example?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this before posting my question but it didn't help.

Comment: did you try changing the paths of both the libraries, like

`g++ -o myexecutable myexecutable.o -L/path-to-my.so/libmy.so /path-to-test.so/libtest.so`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that there's another `libtest` somewhere (maybe as `libtest.a`) that ld is finding first which doesn't have the symbol your program is looking for.

Use the `-Wl,--verbose` option to have the linker provide verbose output about what files it's opening or trying to open.  That should tell you why one run is behaving differently than another, and where the 'rogue' libtest is (if any).

Comment: debug option did the trick to investigate the issue. The library was being picked from a nested location which was hard to investigate without this option. Thanks.